# Join Two Dataframes

Tags: python, join, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have two data sets which I get into two data frames

```
               NAB.AX                                  CBA.AX
                       Close    Volume                                         Close    
    Date                                                  Date
 2013-10-02 06:52:32   36.51   4962900             2013-10-02 06:52:32.082622  21.95
```

As you can see the date format is slightly different. How do I join the two data frames using the date index. So basically use

```
2013-10-02 06:52:32
```

And ignore

```
.082622
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reassign the second DataFrame's index to numpy `datetime64[s]` values:

```
df2.index = df2.index.values.astype('datetime64[s]')
```

---

For example,

```
In [58]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Close':36.51}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-10-02 06:52:32'])); df1

                     Close
2013-10-02 06:52:32  36.51

In [78]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Close':[21.95, 22.95, 23.95]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-10-02 06:52:32.082622', '2013-10-02 06:52:32.09', '2013-10-03 06:52:33.09'])); df2
Out[78]: 
                            Close
2013-10-02 06:52:32.082622  21.95
2013-10-02 06:52:32.090000  22.95
2013-10-03 06:52:33.090000  23.95

In [79]: df2.index = df2.index.values.astype('datetime64[s]'); df2
Out[79]: 
                     Close
2013-10-02 06:52:32  21.95
2013-10-02 06:52:32  22.95
2013-10-03 06:52:33  23.95    

In [80]: df1.join(df2, lsuffix='NAB', rsuffix='_CBA')
Out[80]: 
                     CloseNAB  Close_CBA
2013-10-02 06:52:32     36.51      21.95
2013-10-02 06:52:32     36.51      22.95
```

Or, if you wish to keep all the keys in both indexes, use an outer join:

```
In [81]: df1.join(df2, lsuffix='NAB', rsuffix='_CBA', how='outer')
Out[81]: 
                     CloseNAB  Close_CBA
2013-10-02 06:52:32     36.51      21.95
2013-10-02 06:52:32     36.51      22.95
2013-10-03 06:52:33       NaN      23.95
```